# Is there a way to install 13.10 on btrfs and full disk encryption?

Tags: 13.10, encryption, btrfs

I like the fact that the default desktop Ubuntu installer only requires me to check a single checkbox in order to have a fully encrypted disk in the end 
(which is a requirement within our company, so there is no way around that).

On the other hand, I would like to give btrfs a try ... seems like performance and stability are "OK" by now; and snapshots for backup seem to work great.

But ... there is no way to achieve that with the Ubuntu installer - its "full disk encryption on ext4" ... or "do something else", and then all the work is on my shoulders.

So, are there any "easy" options to install a 64 bit 13.10 on btrfs with fde?

Answer (score 1):

I did some further investigation, and it seems: there is no easy answer.

The thing that is actually pretty easy:

1. Do a fresh install of Ubuntu, including the automatic full disk encryption using LUKS and volume management
2. Right after installation, boot the computer using some external USB/DVD linux
3. From that "USB Linux", use luksOpen and the device mapper to mount the (ext4) partitions
4. Then use the btrfs tooling to change the partition to btrfs
5. Update `/etc/fstab` (for the root partition you just changed) to reflect root is now btrfs, and no longer ext4

I tried that with a 14.04 installation, and it worked without any problem.
BUT: just doing that doesn't make too much sense - in my eyes btrfs is only useful if more of its built-in features are used; for example using btrfs subvolumes instead of lvm groups; and btrfs raid1 for "immediate" backup support. Just using it like ext4 doesn't bring benefits; just performance impacts.

Comment: What type of performance is gained using btrfs?

Comment: Back then when I wrote that answer, performance was **impacted** by using btrfs; depending on your use case, you would see slight to **major** slow down when using btrfs. But it seems that things have improved since then, see https://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2015/03/12/which-is-faster-btrfs-or-ext4/ for example